# Other ways to solve this other than Delta Star Transformation

Tags: circuit-analysis

I solved this using delta star transformation (Zeq = 2/3 ohm), but I can't find other circuit analysis techniques to find the Zeq & Io, any help? [image]

Comment: Ha ! Do you have any ideas of your own ?

Comment: Are you sure Zeq = 2/3 ohm?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [node voltage method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_analysis) with the voltage source Vab as specified. There are five nodes, the two series pairs at the top can be combined in the usual way.

Zeq = Vab/Iab

Comment: Use nodal to find Io but what about the Zeq?

Comment: @yasseen.hesham The circuit is passive (no sources) so the equivalent impedance is the voltage source Vab divided by the resulting current through it.